# Possible arrangements of binary vectors keeping sum fixed in R

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, combinations, permutation

Suppose we have fixed row sums for a matrix (say, *MAT*) of dimension *3 x N* which (i.e the row sums) are = *(RS,LS,NCS)'*. The *N* column vectors are unknown. There are 3 possible choices for each of the *N* column vectors - (1,0,0)', (0,1,0)', (0,0,1)'.

So the **first question** is -

How can we get all possible choices of this matrix *MAT* by keeping the row sums fixed as *(RS,LS,NCS)'* using R software ?

For example - Take *N*=7, *RS*=sum of first row=2, *LS*=sum of second row=2 and *NCS*=sum of third row=3. So  (1,0,0)' will appear twice, (0,1,0)' will also appear twice and (0,0,1)' will appear thrice in the set of *N* columns of that matrix *MAT*. One possible choice of *MAT* is -

1    0    0    0    0    1    0

0    1    0    0    0    0    1

0    0    1    1    1    0    0

I think there will be 7!/(2!x2!x3!)=210 possible choices of *MAT* by keeping the row sum fixed as (2,2,3)'.

But how to get those possible choices of *MAT* using R software ? It should be an array of dimension 3xNxn, where *n* is the number of possible choices of *MAT*.

The **second question** is-

How the solution mechanism changes in the above problem if the possible choices of each of the *N* column vectors of that matrix *MAT* becomes - (1,1,0)', (1,0,0)', (0,1,0)', (0,0,1)' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may make use of the `iterpc` package.

```
library(iterpc)

foo = function(index){
    sapply(index, function(z){as.numeric(c(z==1,z==2,z==3))})
}
```

To get all possible matrices

```
I = iterpc(c(2,2,3), ordered=TRUE)
M = getall(I)
sapply(1:nrow(M), function(i) foo(M[i,]), simplify=FALSE)
```

To get the matrices one by one

```
I = iterpc(c(2,2,3), ordered=TRUE)
foo(getnext(I))
foo(getnext(I))
foo(getnext(I))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Any idea for the second question ?

Comment: Your second question may not be well-defined for some row sums. For example, let `a = c(1,1,0), x=c(1,0,0), y=c(0,1,0), z=c(0,0,1)`. The matrix `[a x y z]` and the matrix `[x x y y z]` will produce the same row sums `c(2,2,1)`. `N` is not well-defined, it may also be difficult to get all "combinations", not to mention the another layer of difficulty of the permutations.